# Is it possible to duplicate a visual in Amazon Quicksight?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I would like to duplicate visuals in Amazon Quicksight. I have multiple charts that I need that all have very similar formatting but different data driving them. I would like to be able to duplicate a visual inside of an analysis with all of its formatting in tact so that I can just swap out the variables rather than regenerating a new chart and going back through all of the formatting.

Edit: this seems like it should be really simple, but I haven't found anyway to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do in latest version of QuickSight. Please check for upgrade.
[image: Deplicate Visual]

Answer (score 0):

I've also tried to find such a feature, but it seems that it is not possible....

Comment: Thanks for looking! Quicksight seems to be lacking a lot of seemingly basic functionality.

Comment: Well at the beginning i liked Quicksight very much, mainly because of the price. But more i try to do, less comfortable i feel with this tool.....

Comment: Ya, I agree. I used it for a bit and it was really quick to pick up, but very limited. I've since went to other visualization tools